# how to print multiply value separate with key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**It should be employers lybrary**

> How to do output like:
> Name -> Bugryanyi
> Post -> accountant
> Expereance -> 7
> etc

`

```
all_staff = {"Name": ["Bagryanyi", "Antonovych", "Kostenko"], "Post": ["accountant", "developer", "roller"], "Experience": [7, 1, 3], "Portfolio": ["Documents", "Python", "joint"], "Efficiency": [97, 45, 83], "Stak": ["account", "Pyt", "blunt"], "Salary": [7000, 2000, 3500]}
```

`

Comment: You can access a python dict as follows, `all_staff["Name"][0]` to print the first name in dict. To learn more you can refer to the following page,  https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write it all, you can just use a for-loop to do it:

```
all_staff = {"Name": ["Bagryanyi", "Antonovych", "Kostenko"], "Post": ["accountant", "developer", "roller"], "Experience": [7, 1, 3], "Portfolio": ["Documents", "Python", "joint"], "Efficiency": [97, 45, 83], "Stak": ["account", "Pyt", "blunt"], "Salary": [7000, 2000, 3500]}

s = ""

for key in all_staff:
    s += str(key) + " -> " + str(all_staff[key][0])  + " "
    
print(s)
```

Or if you want to do it in one line, you can do something like that:

```
all_staff = {"Name": ["Bagryanyi", "Antonovych", "Kostenko"], "Post": ["accountant", "developer", "roller"], "Experience": [7, 1, 3], "Portfolio": ["Documents", "Python", "joint"], "Efficiency": [97, 45, 83], "Stak": ["account", "Pyt", "blunt"], "Salary": [7000, 2000, 3500]}

s = " ".join([str(key) + " -> " + str(all_staff[key][0]) for key in all_staff])

print(s)
```